# post data on WebAPI after save in php Using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have created the code for save data in my custom table using Ajax which is working fine.

After that I want to post these data on the asp.Net API using js/jQuery. How I can post same data on the aps.net.

Here is my HTML form and JS code:

```
<div id="inline1" class="audit-form" style="display: none;">
  <form class="infusion-form" id="infusion-form">
  <h3 style="color: #002046;">Sign Up For a Free Capability Audit </h3>
  <div class="dis_block clearfix">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>First Name *</label>
      <input required class="form-control" id="inf_field_FirstName" name="inf_field_FirstName" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Last Name *</label>
      <input required id="inf_field_LastName" name="inf_field_LastName" type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email *</label>
      <input required id="inf_field_Email" name="inf_field_Email" type="email" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Confirm Email *</label>
      <input required id="inf_field_Phone1" name="inf_field_Phone1" type="email" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center;">
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value ="save_procurement_data" />
      <input type="submit" id="frm_basic_info" class="btn custom-btn" value="NEXT" />

    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
  </div>
```

**JS Code is here**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(document).on('click', '#frm_basic_info', function(e){
    jQuery("#infusion-form").validate({
      rules: {
        inf_field_FirstName: "required",
        inf_field_LastName: "required",
        inf_field_Email: "required",
        inf_field_Phone1: {
          equalTo: inf_field_Email
        }
      },
      messages: {
        inf_field_FirstName: "Please enter your firstname",
        inf_field_LastName: "Please enter your lastname",
        inf_field_Email: "Please enter your email",
        inf_field_Phone1: "Please enter your confirm email correct",
      },
        submitHandler: function (form) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var frmd = new FormData();

        var save_data = jQuery('form').serializeArray();
        jQuery.each(save_data,function(key,input){
          frmd.append(input.name,input.value);
        });
         jQuery.ajax({
           url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
           data: frmd,
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           type: 'POST',
           success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            return false;
           //window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/about-your-organization";
           }
         });
        }
      }); 
  });

});
</script>
```

In the alert I getting alert `data saved success fully`.

Comment: Where are you calling Web Api in your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add one more ajax method after saving in your php Url.

See, in your above ajax success method, check the status then post to Asp.Net Web Api, just like my bellow code,

```
 success: function(data){
      //Here you can check the data and call your Web Api. For example
      if(data == "data saved success fully")
       {
        //Write an ajax method to post data to Web Api
        $.ajax({
          url: 'YourWebApiUrlHere',
          data: frmd,
          type:'Post',
          success: function (data) {
            //Show an alert message here that data saved in Web Api blah blah
            if(data == "Your response from Web Api goes here")//Edit this message
               alert("Data saved using Web Api");
            else
               alert("Failed to save data using Web Api");
           }
          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText); //This is the exception if any issue with server 
           }
          })
        }
       else
          alert("Your data haven't saved in Php Url. Check with server");
       return false;
       }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: How I can alert if API not calling?

Comment: May I know what do you mean by not calling ? You want to show an alert for whether data saved using Web Api or not. Am I Right ? If like that, then you can write an alert message in else part just like I did in case of Php Url.

Comment: Yes, If data not saved on the API then I want to alert message and also want to get error message in case any issue with server calling.

Comment: It's very simple my bro! Check with my updated answer above. If it helps plz don't forget to mark as answer :)